# Node into 2 statements into mssql with 1 route , Update and Insert into ms-sql

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, express

I have a Node app in which I insert into a table, however I now need to also insert into another table

problem is that I'm not understanding how to add a second promise execution

```
var query = "first query...";

var query2 = "new 2nd query...";

request.query(query).then(function(resultset){
    console.log('resultset node', resultset);
    res.json(resultset);

}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('err node', err);
    res.json(err)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just nest them and pass back the outer as before,  or trap the errors with logic , **but this is how I have done it and it works fine**

```
request.query(query).then(function(resultset){
    console.log('resultset node', resultset);
    request.query(query2).then(function(resultset2){
        console.log('inner inserted', resultset2);
    }, function(err){
        console.log('inner query failed', err);
    });

    res.json(resultset);

}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('err node', err);
    res.json(err)
})
```